# Virtualbox and IDS

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, backtrack

I am working on a project for grad school and I am way over my head.  The goal is to set up three VM's, I am using Virtualbox.  One being Windows XP (the victim), the second VM running of form of Snort (playing with Snorby and EasyIDS), and the last VM running Backtrack.  The point of the project is go use backtrack (metasploit) to hack into the XP VM and monitor it with the Snort VM.  The problem I am having is, I have never used VM's before and I can not figure out how to network them properly.  I am able to exploit the XP VM, but I can not figure out how to get the Snort VM to monitor it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Configure each VM with one interface attached to [Internal Network](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal). The **name** you choose must be the same for all VMs.

You will only be able to interact with these on the Vbox console.

There are obviously other ways to do it, but I think this will be easiest for you right now to complete your assignment.

Comment: Since you are running an attack style scenario, and I do not like to assume that you have complete control over your network, I would recommend against putting these VMs on your network. I know that the Univ that I used to work at would have frowned upon this type of activity, and I still would on the networks that I am responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

See if this doesn't offer some guidance:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Comment: Host Only means that the VM can only communicate with the host. It specifically excludes other VMs.

Comment: According to the Virtual Box manual, and my own experience, host-only means that VMs can communicate with each other and the host: `as with bridged networking, the virtual machines can talk to each other and the host as if they were connected through a physical ethernet switch.`